# Google Calendar authentication Access is denied using Client Id and ClientSecret

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

my scenario is simple: I have a Web App that accesses my Google calendar. This App works fine when I run it from my PC using Visual Studio, but it gives an error when I run it on the server.

I'm using Client ID and Client Secret (as seen in my code below) to validate my access to the calendar, and as I said on my PC it works.

I know this is a recurring topic, but I've looked at hundreds of posts about this issue and haven't been able to find anything that shows me what I'm doing wrong.

Many posts have a very old publication date and perhaps something has changed in the API version.

My URI is registered within the Google console in the Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs section

I've seen several posts that say there are differences between running on a PC and running on a server, but the script that performs the validation is too simple (apart from the credentials it has 2 lines, see code below).

Considering that it runs on my PC, could someone (please) guide me on which points I should check to try to identify the error...?

By the way..the error is: Access is denied / Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline........... .

I've been stuck with this problem for over two weeks and so far with no prospect of a solution, I would be very grateful for any help.

My code...

```
Private Async Function GetCalendarService() As Tasks.Task(Of CalendarService)
    Dim credPath As String = Server.MapPath("~\token.json")

    Dim credential As UserCredential
    credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets With {
        .ClientId = "11111111111-hsgdhsgdhsgdhsgdhsgd208b2ta8a9dnba7ue.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        .ClientSecret = "VVVVVV-NNNNN6YYYYYYYYhuPrkoSOcIsigkZZZ"
                    }, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath))


    Return New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential})

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using code designed for ain installed application. Like a desktop application.

`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` opens the consent screen on the machine the code runs on you can **NOT** use it on a web server.

Comment: Hi Linda.. thanks for the response. If I understand what you answered is correct, I use GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync in my script to run it on my server is correct. So I keep thinking that other factors could be causing this Access is denied error

Comment: The error is caused by you using installed application code and then trying to host it on a web server.

Comment: Could you tell me what which code should I use instead... Please.

Comment: Sorry I dent know of any VB web samples for the google .net client library.   Everything i have is for C#.   And there is nothing from the team in the documentation either.